# Are there languages in which adverbs inflect?

Tags: morphology, linguistic-typology, inflection, adverbs, morphological-typology

Are there any languages in which adverbs (in the sense of verb modifiers) inflect to match the verb they modify?

Comment: Presumably with respect to tense in the broad sense: agreement with a subject or object that the verb agrees with would presumably be agreement with the subject or object, not the verb. But maybe subject-agreement would have to be mediated through the verb, in some theory?

Comment: Similar: [Does any language conjugate adverbs?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/8515) But the answer there doesn't have the element of agreement that you seem to be looking for

Comment: In my opinion it does not count but a naive observer might conclude that something like that is happening with внутрь vs внутри, вперед vs впереди.

Comment: Not sure how "match" "verb" and "adverb" are being defined but if time words function adverbially then `yesterday I went to the store` vs. `tomorrow I will go to the store` seems to meet your criteria.

Comment: I have a theory according to which adverbs should decline in a way corresponding to the way subject/object/indirect object do.  But, so far as I know, they don't.  (Please let me know if they do.)

Comment: I don't know if this counts, but in Irish, the prepositions inflect with the pronoun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are supposed to be some languages that have adverbs that show inflectional agreement with the head verb. I don't know enough to give an overview, but one example seems to be Maori, where adverbs modifying a passive verb take passive marking, and those midifying a nominalized verb take nominalizing marking ("[Formal Property Inheritance and Consonant/Zero Alternations in Maori Verbs](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/20cf/825ee589e50b2ffce4c3a64bec2be78868bd.pdf)", by Nicholas Kibre, October 1, 1998; p. 11).